# How to retrieve sorted data from Firebase and display it in text views? (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to collect data from FireBase, in Android Studio, while sorting it using the orderByChild and equalTo functions. Then I'm trying to display the data on text views. The page crashes every time. How can I fix this? Below I've given my code and my database:

```
public class TrackOrder extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private EditText trackText;
    private Button trackBtn;
    private TextView disp, text;

    public void trackBtn (View view){ //opens the admin portal activity
        trackText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trackText);
        disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.disp);
        String trackNumb = trackText.getText().toString();
        disp.setText(trackNumb);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_order);

        String numb = disp.getText().toString();

        trackText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trackText);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        trackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trackBtn);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders"); //Reflecting where the data will be located
        mDatabase.orderByChild("1 order_number").equalTo("4725");
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                text.setText(name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: The Database format]

Comment: You want every node from "Orders" node?

Comment: Can you show logs for crash you're getting.